# Why does this function fire multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems with a function firing multiple times on click. Specifically, in the below code, the userloggedin(); function fires multiple times when clicked. Typically, it fires once the first time, 3 times the next time and 6 the next.

```
var timer = null;
function sessCountdown() {
    var sec = 120;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        sec--;
        if (sec >= 0) {
            span = document.getElementById("count");
            span.innerHTML = sec;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function getUserInfo() {
    var getUserInfo = $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: Config.engineUrl + '?AUserSessionInfo',
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true
    });
    getUserInfo.done(function(data, jqXHR) {
        var sessionModal = $('#session-modal');
        if (data.TimeLeft > 0 && data.TimeLeft <= 2 && !sessionModal.hasClass('in')) {
            sessionModal.modal('show');
            sessCountdown();
        } else if (data.TimeLeft === 0){
        $('.logout').trigger('click');
        }
        sessionModal.on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $('#btnSession').on('click', function() {
                clearInterval(timer);
                userLoggedin();
            });
        });
    });
}

//Check for session info every 60 seconds
setInterval(getUserInfo, 60000);
```

I appreciate any tips for resolving this that you can provide. Thanks.

**Updated Code - With Resolution**

```
var timer = null;

function sessCountdown() {
    var sec = 120;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        sec--;
        if (sec >= 0) {
            span = document.getElementById("count");
            span.innerHTML = sec;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function getUserInfo() {
    var sessionModal = $('#session-modal'),
        getUserInfo = $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: Config.engineUrl + '?AUserSessionInfo',
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true
        });
    getUserInfo.done(function(data, jqXHR) {
        if (data.TimeLeft > 0 && data.TimeLeft <= 2 && !sessionModal.hasClass('in')) {
            sessionModal.modal('show');
            sessCountdown();
        } else if (data.TimeLeft === 0) {
            $('.logout').trigger('click');
        }
    });
}

$('#btnSession').on('click', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    userLoggedin();
});

//Check for session info every 60 seconds
setInterval(getUserInfo, 60000);
```

Comment: It's because you're creating a new `shown.bs.modal` event handler every time the AJAX request completes. Put the event handler *outside* of the AJAX request callback. The `#btnSession` click handler may also need to go outside of the modal shown handler too, but you've not shown enough of your code to tell for certain

Comment: Thanks, Rory. You definitely got me on the right track. I had to (a) put the event handler outside the ajax callback, (b) remove the modal shown handler and (c) move the #btnSession click handler outside of the getUserInfo() function. All is well now. Better yet, I understand the err of my ways. Thanks again.